# Get size of each folders in document management system

Tags: php, linux, document-management

I am using the Document Management System which is created on KnowledgeTree frame work. I want to know the size of each folder created on it. I tried to get the size through server but the files are in non readable format. Is there any possible way to know the file size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does that mean, the files are in non readable format? Certainly the server knows how to read and handle them, otherwise there would be no way to use that document management system.

Comment: [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.filesize.php) is implemented such that it will only fail if the user-access to that file is restricted for apache/php. Non readable formats make no difference because linux won't be reading the content, just checking the amout of storage space it takes up.